# How do you default a column to the current date in GRDB

Tags: swift, grdb

We use GRDB for our iOS application and am adding the following migration:

```
 migrator.registerMigration("v7") { db in
        try db.alter(table: "DocAlertThirdPartyTrackingUrl") { t in
            t.add(column: DocAlertThirdPartyTrackingUrl.CodingKeys.initialDate.rawValue, .date).defaults(to: ?????)
        }
    }
```

Not sure how to set this up so it uses the current date as the default?

Comment: I have no experience with GRDB but did you try using `Date()` for the `defaults(to:)` call?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a default value that is always the current date you need to do it at a database level so use the sql variant of the defaults function

```
.defaults(sql: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```